# Can't Find the how to publish the SAML App to GSuite MarketPlace?

Tags: java

We have created the custom `SAML` app in `GSuite` admin console. Now we have to publish our app in GSuite Marketplace. I checked the marketplace documentation and there's no mention of SAML.Please let me know what steps we need to take to begin the submission process.